# C++ Generic Class methods acting strange and ignoring values I'm providing to it

Tags: c++, templates

I decided to finally learn C++ and I'm messing around with generics, but I encountered pretty strange behavior.

```cpp
// generic_linked_list.h
namespace generic_linked_list {
    template<typename A>
    struct Node {
        A val;
        Node<A>* next;
    };

    template<typename A>
    class LinkedList {
    public:
        Node<A>* first;
        Node<A>* last;
        void append(A a);
        A* head();
        A* tail();
    };
}
```

```cpp
#include "generic_linked_list.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace generic_linked_list {
    template<typename A>
    void LinkedList<A>::append(A a) {
        std::cout << "adding ";
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        auto next = Node<A>{.val = a, .next = nullptr};
        std::cout << next.val << std::endl;
        if (this->last) {
            this->last->next = &next;
            this->last = this->last->next;
        } else if (this->first) {
            this->last = &next;
            this->first->next = &next;
        } else {
            std::cout << "setting first" << std::endl;
            this->first = &next;
            std::cout << this->first->val << std::endl;
        }   
    }

    template<typename A>
    A* LinkedList<A>::head() {
        if (this->first) {
            std::cout << "getting ";
            std::cout << this->first->val << std::endl;
            return &this->first->val;
        }
        
        return nullptr;
    };

    template<typename A>
    A* LinkedList<A>::tail() {
        if (this->last) 
            return &this->last->val;
        
        return nullptr;
    };
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
generic_linked_list::LinkedList<int>* ll = new generic_linked_list::LinkedList<int>();
ll->append(a);
std::cout << *ll->head() << std::endl;
```

For some reason it always prints 241622424, it is probably some kind of reference, but I cannot find where I made a mistake. And I cant even google that because I have no idea what am I doing wrong, please help...

I've added some debug logging but it seems to work fine until I'm calling method `head()`.

Comment: Recommendation: format these snippets into a proper [mre] (MRE) and your question will be better-received. As an added bonus, MRE is a distillation of a few powerful debugging techniques, so odds are good that you'll find the source of your troubles while making the MRE.

Comment: @user3751379 Ths declaration auto next = Node<A>{.val = a, .next = nullptr}; declares a local variable that will not be alive after exiting the function

Comment: Side note: Keep an eye out for this problem, assuming this problem isn't what really spawned this question: https://godbolt.org/z/cnEa1E6jM . Yeah what Vlad just said, but with more diagnostics.

Comment: @user3751379  Also this if statement } else if (this->first) {
            this->last = &next;
            this->first->next = &next;
        } does not make sense.

Comment: It is just as much broken if you don't use a template. Try to implement the list for `int` first and then generalize. Otherwise you get distracted by irrelevant details that are not related to your problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how do I declare it so it's not freed after exiting the function?

Comment: @user17732522 this is very much related to my problem

Comment: Which C++ textbook are you using to learn C++? I would expect that every C++ textbook would first explains the fundamental concepts of dynamically-scoped objects, and how to create and destroy them, before introducing the subject of templates, and other advanced C++ topics that are used in the shown code. I would expect that every C++ textbook would cover dynamically-scoped objects, discussing them in details, before introducing advanced template concepts used here.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and it will tell you [exactly what's wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/401237b1d874c209).  You need to allocate your `Node`s with `new`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not reading any book

Comment: @MilesBudnek thank you, that would probably solve my problem, will try that

Comment: @user3751379 That your code is using templates is completely irrelevant to the problem you observe. Take a step back to the basics and try to implement a linked list for `int` values first. Then you can come back to the more advanced topic of templates and generalize your `int` linked-list to arbitrary element types.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I've also added warnings to my builds, thanks a lot again

Comment: @user3751379 Just remember you'll also need to `delete` your `Node`s when you're finished with them.

Comment: @MilesBudnek yes, I know I have to free the memory myself now...